# enable DNSSEC on workstation

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, dnssec

our office servers offer DNSSEC. I've tested this with dig.

how can i use DNSSEC with my RHEL6 workstation? (there is no bind on it...)

is it possible to add trusted keys to the workstation (i.e. in /etc/resolv.conf )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [`unbound`](http://www.unbound.net/) as the local recursive server and set your `resolv.conf` to point to `127.0.0.1`.

Unbound has full DNSSEC validation built in, and is designed solely for recursive service so doesn't have all of the authoritative service baggage that BIND has.